# How to return the data object from the get request made by the HttpClient in the Angular?

Tags: angular, api, http

I'm trying to get a response from my API using HttpClient. Whenever I try to set `this.items = data` in my component, no data is transferred to the `items` variable and it is undefined on scope.

That are my service class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { PacoteAPI } from './classes/pacoteAPI';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable(/*{ providedIn: 'root' }*/)

export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getDataApi() {
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:3001/query');
  }
}
```

This is my component that consumes the service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-listar',
  templateUrl: './listar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listar.component.css']
})

export class ListarComponent implements OnInit {
  public items: Object;


  constructor(private api: ApiService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getDataApi().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data.length);
      this.items = data;
    });
    console.log(this.items.length);
  }

}
```

I print the two lengths on the console to compare, the first print shows `2`
and the second impression shows `undefined`.

How do I to get the data inside the `.subscribe`? I really need this data.

Comment: The data is only available with `subscribe` block so your `this.items = data;` should work but you cannot print the value outside the block. This would not work `console.log(this.items.length);`

Comment: Can not I pass the data out of the application?

Comment: Could be bad json from the network. Also, you should be using the generic method of the http.get => http.get<Type of Your Return>

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to use items in your template, you can also consider using async pipe and let Angular manage the subscription for you ... `{{ items | async }}`

**Edit:**
To use your data in *ngFor loop, you will want to use async pipe like this:

```
// in the controller:
export class ListarComponent implements OnInit {
  public items: Object;
  items$: Observable<any[]>;


  constructor(private api: ApiService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items$ = this.api.getDataApi();
  }

}

// In the template
<div *ngFor="let item of items$ | async>
// do something with item
</div>
```

Here is an working example on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ovuo1w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I need to put this data into the variable of my class. How do I do that?

Comment: I wat to use this data in *ngFor for place some items on pane

Comment: You can take a look on my edited response and play with the Stackblitz example. Enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

What you did is absolutely correct

```
public items: Object;
constructor(private api: ApiService) {}
ngOnInit() {
  this.api.getDataApi().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data.length);
    this.items = data;
  });
  console.log(this.items.length);
}
```

after you subscribe to the `getDataApi`, you try to store the result in component property `items`. Only then you have the data

In your template, your data might not be availabel immediately, ex.

```
<div *ngIf="items"></div>
```

So you might want to put a `ngIf`, otherwise you might have error when `items` is null.